# Create a command to display extensions of regular files in current directory with counts to each extension. Files without extension should be ignored

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, terminal

Suppose you have these files in your current directory:

```
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2/testers (cs3300-301722)$ ls
bar  emp.lst  foo  q5.sh  q6.sh  q7.sh  q8.sh
```

My desired output is:

```
      1 lst
      4 sh
```

I am able to print out the file extensions with the counts as shown above however I can't quite figure out how to exclude the files without extensions. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing? I will provide my command and output below:

```
ifsmy12@cloudshell:~/3300/tests/t2/testers (cs3300-301722)$ find . -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
      1 /bar
      1 /foo
      1 lst
      4 sh
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could just add `-name '*\.*'` to your find clause.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a pattern to match at least a `.` followed by matching 1+ times any char except `.` or `/` until the end of the string `$`

```
.*\.[^/.]+$
```

For example

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.[^/.]+$' | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Output

```
1 lst
4 sh
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
find . -type f | sed -n 's/.*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c
```

For the sed command: turn on the `-n` option which requires explicit printing and then use the substitution flag `p` to print on a successful substitution.